# How do I access the svg/vml element of a kartograph.js map?

Tags: jquery, kartograph

With [kartograph.js](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.js) I can access the container element of my map like this: `mymap.container`. But how do I get the actual SVG (or VML) element?

`$(mymap.container).find("svg,vml")` works, but feels stupid.

In the end, I want to be able to manipulate some attributes of the element (namely `preserveAspectRatio`, `width` and `height`).

Comment: If you just want to write it ìn some different way you can write `$("svg,vml", mymap.container)`

Comment: Sure, I was just hoping that there would be a way to access the element withouth having to make jQuery search for it (in theory, some other svg or vml object could have been injected in the same container after loading the map, etc).